# What are the advatanges of using templates?

Tags: php, templates, smarty, laravel

I have heard people talking about advantages of using templates to separate the view from logic. But if any one is using a  framework, then the view and logic are already separated.I want to know from those who have used templates, what are the benefits they see using it, apart from separation of view and logic, easy for designer to work separately, nice looking code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is an open question, have a look to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). If you want to know benefits of template, have a look to the [MVC architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: @ninsuo I am aware about MVC architecture My question is why do we need templates even code separation can be achieved using MVC architecture. I want to know what are other advantages of using templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to answer most of it yourself, but I can add that Smarty also has a built in caching system which "compiles" the templates into php for faster rendering.

Comment: caching can also be achieved using caching in CodeIgniter and other frameworks.What are the advantages of smarty over this ?

Comment: Smarty can cache chunks of content and keep other chunks dynamically rendered. This can be used somewhat similarly to ESI. Also lots of devs are already familiar with smarty syntax/features. It brings lots of helpers like `{$smarty.foreach.foo.last}` to check if it is the last element in the collection (array, iterable, …) etc. pp.